# Move slick navigation arrows inside the slides

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

How can I move the navigation arrows? Would like them to be on the sliders images. I have tried everything I could find on the web, no results. Using ASP.NET don't think that it matters though. Using the latest SLICK version.

HTML code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Slick.WebForm1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
   <title>Slideshow</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
</head> 
<body><div class="slider-for">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="slider">
    <img src="\img\koral.jpg" /> 
    <img src="\img\ships.jpg" />  
        </div>
    </form></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/Instellingen.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

My JS settings:

```
$('.slider-for').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    fade: true,
    swipe: false,
    accessibility: false,
    arrows: false,
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slider').slick({
        slide: 'img',
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        arrows: true,
        centerMode: true,
        variableWidth: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,
        appendArrows: $('img'),
        appendDots: $('img')


    });

});
```

EDIT: Found out the problem was that my cache wasn't refreshing..
There is one arrow under the slideshow now, how can i move it to the front?

Comment: You're using some JavaScript files we don't have access to. Please turn your issue into a Fiddle, so we can look into it

Comment: No clue how Fiddle works, sorry. Here are all the files you will need: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/tree/master/slick

Comment: You can't just put a download link here to some files. You will need to upload code that we can instantly run or upload it to jsfiddle.net, where you can easily include plugins and such

Answer (score 2):

Try using CSS to move navigation buttons inside slider. For example:

```
.slick-prev {
    left: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.slick-next {
    right: 25px;
}

.slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before {
   color: #000;
}
```

Comment: I wish it was that easy, didn't change anything

Comment: I got it moved now, but you see the slider over the buttons. any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: Try changing CSS z-index property for button.